# Polymorphism and DRY when constructing new objects

Tags: java

Suppose I have :

```
class FooMom {
   String momField1;
   Integer momField2;
   ...
   String momField10;
}
```

And a child class:

```
class Foo extends FooMom {
   String extraField;
}
```

How can I refactor this code bellow

```
FooMom fooMom ;

if (someCondition) {
    fooMom = new FooMom("momField1", ..., "momField10");
}
else {
    fooMom = new Foo("momField1", ..., "momField10", "extraField");
}
```

I don't like the repetition of `"momField1", ..., "momField10"` in the two constructors

Is there a way like

```
FooMom fooMom = new FooMom("momField1", ..., "momField10");
if (!someCondition) {
    // adding the extraField to Foo instance
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Multiple possibilities:

- If the parameters are only Strings, maybe use a `String[]` or `String...`
- Use a DTO (Data Transfer Object) that encapsulates the data, and pass that on to both `FooMom` and `Foo`
- Create and instance of `FooMom` first, and have something like a Copy-Constructor in  `Foo`: `public Foo(FooMom original, String extraField) {...}` that copies the values of the original/passed object
- You can use Lambda calls, and pass Lambda calls (something like `Function`s or `Consumer`s) to the CTORs of the objects, this will reduce repitition but make the whole thing more verbose

**This is IMO the most elegant solution, implementing suggestion #3:**

```
public class ChainedCTORs_Example3 {

    static class FooMom {
        private final String    momField1;
        private final Integer   momField2;
        private final String    momField10;
        //      public FooMom(final FooMom pOriginal) { // classical Copy-CTOR
        //          momField1 = pOriginal.momField1;
        //          momField2 = pOriginal.momField2;
        //          momField10 = pOriginal.momField10;
        //      }
        public FooMom(final FooMom pOriginal) { // Alternative Copy-CTOR with CTOR Chaining, same effect
            this(pOriginal.momField1, pOriginal.momField2, pOriginal.momField10);
        }
        public FooMom(final String pMomField1, final Integer pMomField2, final String pMomField10) {
            momField1 = pMomField1;
            momField2 = pMomField2;
            momField10 = pMomField10;
        }
    }

    static class Foo extends FooMom {
        private final String extraField;
        public Foo(final FooMom pFooMom, final String pExtraField) {
            super(pFooMom);
            extraField = pExtraField;
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final boolean someCondition = Math.random() < 0.5;

        FooMom fooMom = new FooMom("momField1", Integer.valueOf(667), "momField10");
        if (!someCondition) {
            fooMom = new Foo(fooMom, "extraField");
        }
    }

}
```

*Remark:* I made those fields `final` so initialization is guaranteed (in-code proof it works), and `private` as default.

**Example for suggestion #4:**

```
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class LambdaCtors_Example4 {

    static class FooMom {
        private final String    momField1;
        private final Integer   momField2;
        private final String    momField10;
        public FooMom(final Supplier<String> pS1, final Supplier<Integer> pS2, final Supplier<String> pS3) {
            momField1 = pS1.get();
            momField2 = pS2.get();
            momField10 = pS3.get();
        }
    }

    static class Foo extends FooMom {
        private final String extraField;
        public Foo(final Supplier<String> pS1, final Supplier<Integer> pS2, final Supplier<String> pS3, final Supplier<String> pS4) {
            super(pS1, pS2, pS3);
            extraField = pS4.get();
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final boolean someCondition = Math.random() < 0.5;

        final Supplier<String> s1 = () -> "momField1";
        final Supplier<Integer> s2 = () -> Integer.valueOf(667);
        final Supplier<String> s3 = () -> "momField10";
        final Supplier<String> s4 = () -> "extraField";
        FooMom fooMom = new FooMom(s1, s2, s3);
        if (!someCondition) {
            fooMom = new Foo(s1, s2, s3, s4);
        }
    }

}
```

*Remark:* This is not quite as elegant as the CTOR Chaining solution.
However, if the creation/access to resources is the bottleneck, this is the best solution, as data is only created and Lambdas are only run when really needed.

Info: The execution of Lambda expressions in Java is no bit slower than running 'normal' code.

Of course, in the example above, assigning simple `String`s is not a situation where one would need this. However, late/Lazy construction of data can be a big advantage in a lot of cases.

Comment: I have edited my question, can you give us a example of your 4th possibility ?

Comment: Kudos for the first two possibilities.

Comment: Well, I miss the builder pattern here. Constructors with that many parameters are often avoided and replaced with a builder. The builder of `FooMom` can then extend the builder of `Foo`.

Comment: Yes, indeed. But that would require an additional class. And in its easiest implementation, a Copy CTOR, too (not using the CopyCTOR you would have the same 'problem' of repitition, but placed it in another class). Using an additional class, we could also use a simple Factory Pattern.